# *** glibc detected *** ./333: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0804b008 ***

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ALFA 4

int simVarDiscr(int* nr, int l, int nrm) {
    int k = 0, i = 1;
    double p, q;
    q = (double)ALFA / (ALFA + l - 1);
    p = (double)nr[1] / (ALFA + l - 1);
    double F = p;
    double u = genrand_real3(); // random number in (0,1) dont matter this
    if (u > q)
        return nrm + 1;
    else {
        while (u > F) {
            k++;
            p = (double)nr[i] / (ALFA + l - 1);
            i++;
            F += p;
        }
        return k;
    }
}

int main() {
    int* nr, i, nrm, a;
    nr = (int*)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    nr[0] = 1;
    nrm = 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        a = simVarDiscr(nr, i, nrm);
        if (a > nrm) {
            nrm++;
            nr = (int*)realloc(nr, (nrm + 1) * sizeof(int));
            nr[nrm] = 1;
        } else {
            nr[a]++;
        }
        printf("%d --- %d\n", a, nr[i]);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Hi I have this error:

> ```
> *** glibc detected *** ./333: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0804b008 ***
> ======= Backtrace: =========
> /lib/libc.so.6(+0x6dffb)[0xb7759ffb]
> /lib/libc.so.6(+0x71640)[0xb775d640]
> /lib/libc.so.6(realloc+0xf3)[0xb775ec43]
> ./333[0x8048876]
> /lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfe)[0xb7702c0e]
> ======= Memory map: ========
> ```

I want to increase a number from nr given by simVarDisc. It's similar with Chinese Restaurant Process. 
If returned value by SimVarDisc is greater by nrm I want to realloc in nr.
I'm stuck here, other problems like this on SO aren't working...

If I print

> printf("%d --- %d\n", a, nr[i]);

it will show:

> 2 --- 0 
>   0 --- 1
>   3 --- 1
>   Then error above.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: it was my mistake, it should be 0, same with 0

Comment: You have a problem with your memory allocations - but you knew that. Since you are probably on Linux or maybe some BSD, I recommend installing the Valgrind tool, as the Valgrind memory analyzer can directly tell you about memory problems (including full stack traces of where they occur.)

Comment: `nr[a]++;` : There is a possibility to destroy the areas other than the secured.

Comment: I don't understand what secured means...

Comment: This type of error occurs when you have written outside of your allocated buffer, but I can't see that happening anywhere in your code. (There are some reads outside the buffer, but that shouldn't matter). **Are you sure** that the code you have posted is **exactly** the same as the one giving the error? Has it been simplified in **any way**?

Comment: Yes it is simplified... Here is full version: http://pastebin.com/ywJ1jWkr  @Nisse Engström

Comment: That code is very different and is full of memory-related bugs. Stop wasting our time and post some code that is **actually** producing an error.

Answer (score 0):

You check to see if your array index `a` is larger than the array size `nrm`. But what you need to do is check if it is **equal** or larger.

The only element you can access in an array of size 1 is index 0. If you write into index 1 you have written outside of the array.

Comment: The code is allocating `nrm+1` elements so the comparison shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @NisseEngström: You shouldn't rely on that. Your `nrm` should be the size of the array. Otherwise you (or others working on the code) will make mistakes. As evidenced by the fact that you malloc *1 element* and set `nrm` to 1 during the initial setup.